# How to calculate the integer $K$?

Tags: probability, statistics

> The number of policies that an agent sells has a Poisson distribution
>   with modes at $2$ and $3$. $K$ is the smallest number such that the
>   probability of selling more than $K$ policies is less than 25%.
>   Calculate K.

I know that the parameter lambda is $3$, of the Poisson distribution but I'm not sure how to calculate the integer $K$.

Correct answer: 4.

Comment: How do you mean by "modes at 2 and 3"?

Comment: They give us the two modes to have the mean of the distribution (I believe) wich is Lambda equal 3. But I don't know how to use it to obtain K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the probability mass function of a Poisson-distributed random variable $X$ is $$\Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  If the mode is at $X = 2$ and $X = 3$, this means $$\Pr[X = 2] = \Pr[X = 3],$$ or $$e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^2}{2!} = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^3}{3!},$$ or $3 \lambda^2 = \lambda^3$, or $\lambda = 3$ (since we require $\lambda > 0$).  Then we sequentially compute $\Pr[X \le x]$ for $x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, until we find the first instance $X = K$ where this value is greater than $0.75$, thus implying that $\Pr[X > K] < 0.25$.  Clearly, we have $$\Pr[X \le x] = \sum_{k=0}^x e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!},$$ so we just try it out.  $$\Pr[X \le 0] \approx 0.0497871, \\ \Pr[X \le 1] \approx 0.199148, \\ \Pr[X \le 2] \approx 0.42319, \\ \Pr[X \le 3] \approx 0.647232, \\ \Pr[X \le 4] \approx 0.815263. $$  Therefore, $K = 4$ is the smallest value for which $\Pr[X > K] < 0.25$.

Answer (score 0):

Then that's completely wrong. If Pr[X>K]<0.25, and K = 4. The equation becomes Pr[X>4]. Which is the probability that X is greater than or equal to 5. However, if we let K=3, then Pr[X>3] is the probability that X is greater than or equal to 4. K=3 is the smallest number at which "selling more than K policies (aka. 4 or more) is less than 25%.

Comment: Can you please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the formatting of your mathematics?  That will make it much easier to understand what you have written.  May I also suggest that the first sentence is superfluous and kind of condescending?  You may want to consider removing it.